# validation in react hook form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a form that I want to validate on one of the input and i use react hook form .
This is the validation I want to apply:

```
const validateSheba=(str)=> {
    var pattern = /IR[0-9]{24}/;
    
    if (str.length !== 26) {
      return false;
    }
  
    if (!pattern.test(str)) {
      return false;
    }
  
    var newStr = str.substr(4);
    var d1 = str.charCodeAt(0) - 65 + 10;
    var d2 = str.charCodeAt(1) - 65 + 10;
    newStr += d1.toString() + d2.toString() + str.substr(2, 2);
    
    var remainder = this.iso7064Mod97_10(newStr);
    if (remainder !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
  
    return true;
  };
```

And that's how I used it:

```
                <Input
                name="Sheba"
                placeholder="Sheba"
                ref={register({
                    required: true,
                    pattern: {
                      value:value=> validateSheba(value),
                      message: "not valid",
                    },
                  })}
                  error={errors?.Sheba ? true : false}
                  helperText={errors?.Sheba?.message}
                inputClassName={classes.input}
              ></Input>
```

It does not work .. How should I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to change `register({ ... })` to `...register({ ... })`?

Comment: Yes, but it does not work

Comment: Could you please share executable code to stackbiltz or codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you are using a function for the validation, not a regex. The prop *pattern* is used for regex.

Please check this codesandbox example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-js-forked-5kep0?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

The register method returns multiple values [`{ onChange, onBlur, name, ref }`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) that need to be registered with the input. E.g.

```
<Input {...register("test")} />
```

You assign the returned object to `ref`. I guess that is wrong, but I don't know how your `Input` component is implemented.

Here is an executable example. Just click `Run code snippet` at the bottom.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useContext, useRef, useMemo } = React;
const { useForm } = ReactHookForm;

const App = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  }; // your form submit function which will invoke after successful validation

  const nameRequired = errors.name && errors.name.type === "required";
  const namePattern = errors.name && errors.name.type === "pattern";

  const wrongAge = errors.age;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input
          {...register("name", {
            required: true,
            pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i
          })}
          className="form-control"
        />
        {nameRequired && <p>This field is required</p>}
        {namePattern && <p>Alphabetical characters only</p>}
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input
          {...register("age", { min: 18, max: 99 })}
          className="form-control"
        />
        {wrongAge && (
          <p>You Must be older then 18 and younger then 99 years old</p>
        )}
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-hook-form@7.11.1/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```